# Google Sheets Script to keep track of the last time a cell was edited

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

For instance, if I have Column A and Column B and I make a change today in Column A, I like for it to automatically pop up in Column B with the date it was edited.

This is the script Im working with right now.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var d = new Date()
e.source.getActiveSheet()
.getRange('I6')
.setValue('UPDATED\n' +d
   .toLocaleDateString() + '\n' )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to identify:

- the edited Column = `e.range.columnStart`
- the edited Row = `e.range.rowStart`
- the edited Sheet = `e.range.getSheet().getName()`

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.range.getSheet().getName())
    var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    var editedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),timeZone ,"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2).setValue(editedDate)
  } 
}
```

---

**RESULTS**

[image: snapshot]